# Lucene - is it possible to add a document to the "beginning" of the index

Tags: lucene.net

As the heading states, is it possible to add a new doc at a specific place? The reason for this is to avoid the overhead of sorting in the query.

Background: I regularly write a batch of docs in a specific order, but also write individual,ad-hoc docs at random. I want these ad-hoc docs to appear at the **beginning** of the search results WITHOUT adding a field sort to the query. Is this possible?

**Alternatively**, is it possible to make lucene return the docs in the opposite order to which they exist in the index? That way I could alter the order of the batch process and invert the results as a whole e.g. add sort direction to
`searcher.Search(query, null, endIndex, Sort.INDEXORDER);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the answer is NO for the same reason that you can't add a new row to a SQL table at a specific point in the table - you can't just guess an available id which would exist at an 'earlier' position in the table.

In fact, I can't find documentation about inserting your own Document ID in lucene. If this is, in fact, possible - I'd love to know